# Inducing ActivityManager to "No longer want" for testing

Tags: android

I'm trying to test how my application handles getting destroyed by the Android `ActivityManager` (and later restarted by Alarm events).
In other words, I want to force the message:

```
I/ActivityManager(  333): No longer want com.myname.myapp (pid 4444): hidden #22
```

**Is there a way to *reliably* induce the `ActivityManager` to "No longer want" my application?**

A few tricks I know for ending processes (however, the purpose of this question is to find something to induce the `ActivityManager` method of "No longer want").

- Using Manage Applications, touch the button "Force Stop". 
   The problem with this is it doesn't always seem to behave quite the same as the `ActivityManager` "No longer want" method.
- Run many memory hogging applications.  
   The problem with this is it's unreliable and time-consuming.  Sometimes I can run lots of applications and I don't see a peep from `ActivityManager`.
- OS API [`killBackgroundProcesses()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses%28java.lang.String%29) .  
  The problem with this is it was not clear if calling `killBackgroundProcesses()` explicitly would behave *exactly the same* as the `ActivityManager` "No longer want" method.

Answer (score 1):

In the newer version of Android there is a option of "Don't keep activities". After selecting that every activity gets destroyed as soon as the user leaves the Activity. For example we have activity A and B.
Normal Flow

- Activity A starts activity B

After selecting Don't keep activities

- Activity A start activity B
- B -> onCreate , A -> onDestroy (note
     that A doesn't call finish after starting activity B)
- Pressing back button takes you back to Activity A